# Is there a way to use a percent value in window.scrollTo()

Tags: javascript, measure, units-of-measurement

I have a `window.scrollTo()` function on my website. It uses just a number value (or pixels) which works fine in a larger-sized window but does not scroll where I want on mobile devices. Instead, I want to use a percent value (or some dynamic unit) so it scrolls where I want on all devices.

Comment: Percentage of _what_, though? Note that it is not possible to (naively) scroll to "100%" because that would mean the top of the browser's viewport is _after the end_ of the document, but all browsers prevent users from scrolling the _bottom_ of the viewport beyond the document's height.

Comment: _"but does not scroll where I want on mobile devices."_ - **that's a bug in your code**, you should fix that _properly_ instead of trying hack-ish workarounds like this.

Comment: Maybe scrollintoview is what you are searching for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can measure the screen height and then divide by 100 and with it, you get the unit with percentage.

```js
let unit = document.documentElement.scrollHeight / 100;

const onScroll = () => {
  console.log(unit)
  window.scrollTo({ top: 30 * unit });
}
```

```css
body {
   height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="onScroll()">Scroll</button>
```